# How to read complex data from TB size binary file, fast and keep the most accuracy?

Tags: python, numpy

Use Python 3.9.2 read the beginning of TB size binary file ([piece of it](https://file.io/O5K6v2ymVEfl)) as  below:

```
file=open(filename,'rb')
bytes=file.read(8)
print(bytes)
b'\x14\x00\x80?\xb5\x0c\xf81'
```

I tried `np.fromfile` `np.fromfile(np.complex64)` ways to read the file `filename`.

```
float_data1 = np.fromfile(filename,np.float32)
float_data2 = np.fromfile(filename,np.complex64)
```

As the binary file always bigger than 500GB,even TB size,how to read complex data from TB size binary file, fast and keep the most acuuracy?

Comment: Print `samples[0]` instead of `samples[:1]`.

Comment: Note that loading 1 TiB in RAM is certainly a very bad idea as it requires at least 1 TiB of RAM. Due to possibly two buffer stored in memory and the OS, you may need actually 2 TiB or RAM... Not to mention Numpy tends to often make array copy and temporary array. If you do not have so much memory (available only on very very few expensive servers in the world), then the array will be stored on the disk which is insane. It means you load data from the disk to then store it again in the disk to relead them again and again every time it is needed. Not surprising this is very slow!

Comment: `print` cannot be trusted to check the accuracy of numbers. It only print few digits. `np.fromfile` should read the binary data without loss of precision unless you are on a non-IEEE-conforming platform (which is very unlikely to be the case, and if so, the precision of the read array will certainly the least of your problem). If you want to check the accuracy of the loaded number you need to *compute the difference* and *then* print it.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Isn't `print` only showing too few digits when printing *arrays*, like when they print `samples[:1]`? When I printed `samples[0]` instead, I got the same more digits as their method 3.

Comment: @KellyBundy It cannot be trusted in both cases, but yes, the pretty-printing of arrays is designed to print less digits (so to print more item per row). Printing `v.astype(str)` show more digits (though it still cannot be trusted too).

Comment: @JérômeRichard For *Python* `float` (and I think also `complex`) it can be trusted, right? It's just *NumPy* float/complex that can't be trusted? Btw I benchmarked their method3 list comprehension with 1.6 MB of source data. With the same speed, 1 TB would take ~75 hours, not 6. And 1 TB is likely slower speed for the memory/disk reasons you mentioned. So I suspect they actually have far less than 1 TB.

Comment: @kittygirl How large is your file, exactly? And how long did `method1` take?

Comment: @KellyBundy Well the printed float value in Python is quite accurate but not perfect either when you care about high-precision. Python printing round numbers regarding the precision of floats on the target platform. For example `print(math.pi+1/3-math.pi-1/3+1)` gives `1.0000000000000002` which is quite fair. But you should keep in mind that the '...00002' is rounded and the actual value is '...000016653345...'. AFAIK, `print` should show the result with up to few time the epsilon precision as the error. IDK, how `print` deals with sub-normal numbers or if it even supports them...

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, I know Python doesn't show *all* digits of a `float`, I just meant we can trust the prints for (in)equality observations as this question does. As far as I know, it doesn't show *"up to few time the epsilon precision as the error"* but shows exactly as much as necessary to reproduce the same value. Meaning any two different float values get printed differently. So two values are equal if and only if their prints are equal.

Comment: @KellyBundy Two exact same values should be printed the same way indeed which is sufficient for the OP question. However, I am not sure that a decimal representation is always bound to one unique value (probably due to sub-normal numbers which are special). At least, this is not the case for NaN values (there are many of them).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I checked the string representations of the smallest million positive floats, they went from `'5e-324'` to `'4.940656e-318'` and they were all different.

Comment: @KellyBundy Indeed. They even support `-0.0` which I though not to be supported. Thus, except the multiple NaN, the representation seems to be a bijection with the float values.

Comment: @KellyBundy,the binary file come from `Gnuradio` is around 1GB/second,certainly beyond TB size，cost 6 hours.

Comment: .... how many times do I need to repeat that **your** interpration of the bytes values is incorrect, @kittygirl? You interpret them as float64, but they are float32.

Comment: @MarcusMüller,this is python post.I interpret the data type with the bytes compare.Did you try this? You can download or generate file to test.

Comment: @JérômeRichard,till now,can I say the correct data type is `float 64`?

Comment: @kittygirl ... again **you cannot say the correct data type is float 64**. It's not. It really, really, really isn't. The documentation says that. The source code says that. I say that (and I was the chief architect of GNU Radio for 3 years); User jdv on ham.SE said that. For some reason you insist on reading it as float64. I don't know why. Please stop.

Comment: @MarcusMüller,really thanks for your kindly remind.Through compare the `bytes` content,only `float64` match the bytes.And I upload a piece of binary file. **Python regard float 64 is correct data type** ,unless you provide python code to support float 32.

Comment: seriously, I'm getting tired. Python accepting your instruction to use float64 to interpret the data **says exactly nothing** about the data, it only says something about you. And I've provided code, here in my answer, and in the block docs. The bytes you gave give perfectly logical 32 bit float values, much more sensible than your float64 values. I really really don't know how you think what you claim is right!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Apparently they think that because `print(np.array(1.0000024).tobytes())` doesn't match their file, that means `1.0000024` is wrong. Not realizing that with `print(np.array(1.0000024, dtype=np.float32).tobytes())`, it does match the file.

Comment: @KellyBundy yeah, but I really tried in this and the (deleted when I clicked on "post answer") question on ham.SE ten times: Any advice to actually try the thing the domain experts, the documentation, the program they used for design and the source code tell them was met with deaf ears :(

Comment: I really just want to help kittygirl, but it's a bit hard.

Answer (score 3):

This is [related](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/20630/which-python-datatype-should-be-used-to-process-file-sink-of-complex32-signa/20635#20635) to your ham post.

> `samples = np.fromfile(filename, np.complex128)`

and

> Those codes equal to -1.9726906072368233e-31,+3.6405886029665884e-23.

No, they don't equal that. That's just **your** interpretation of bytes as float64. That interpretation is incorrect!

You assume these are 64-bit floating point numbers. They are not; you really need to stop assuming that; it's wrong, and we can't help you if you still act as if it were 64-bit floats forming a 128 bit complex value.

> [Besides documents,I compare the byte content in the answer,that is more than reading docs.](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/20630/which-python-datatype-should-be-used-to-process-file-sink-of-complex32-signa/20635#comment36120_20635)

As I already pointed out, that is *wrong*. Your computer can read anything as any type, just as you tell them, even if it's not the original type it's been stored in. You stored `complex64`, but read `complex128`. That's why your values are so inplausible.

It's 32-bit floats, forming a 64 bit complex value. The [official block documentation](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/File_Sink) for the file sink also points that out, and even explains the numpy dtype you need to use!

Anyways, you can use numpy's [memmap](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) functionality to map the file contents without reading them all to RAM. That works. Again, you need to use the right `dtype`, which is, to repeat this the 10th time, **not** `complex128`.

It's really easy:

```py
data = numpy.memmap(filename, dtype=numpy.complex64)
```

done.